# Foreach for Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've a Multidimensional Array:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => Kolkata Knight Riders v Delhi Daredevils
    [1] => Kolkata
  ) 
  [1] => Array (
    [0] => Royal Challengers Bangalore v Mumbai Indians
    [1] => Bangalore
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [0] => Sunrisers Hyderabad v Pune Warriors 
    [1] => Hyderabad (Deccan)
  ) 
  [3] => Array (
    [0] => Delhi Daredevils v Rajasthan Royals 
    [1] => Delhi
  )
  ... 3 more elements
)
```

I want to:

- `explode` each first element of the array elements on basis of "v", so that I can get `team A` separate from `Team B.` (e.g. `array[0][0]` separates `Kolkata Knight Riders` and `Delhi Daredevils`).
- Create a new array in which I want to remove spaces between team name from both exploded arrays (e.g. `Sunrisers Hyderabad` become `SunrisersHyderabad`).

I've tried the following code:

```php
$i = 0;
foreach($match1 as $value){
    $teams[$i] = explode(' v ', $value[0]); // Exploding teams
    $teams[$i] = strip_tags($teams[$i], 'a'); // Eliminating html

    $teamA[] = explode(' ', $team[$i][0]); // Eliminating Space in Team Name

    $teamA[] = trim($match2[$i]); // Removing white spaces
    $teamB[] = str_replace(' ', '', $team[$i][1]); // Trying Str_Replace method
    $teamB[] = trim($match3[$i]); // Removing White Spaces
    $i++;
}
```

Above code doesn't seem to fill my all requirements. Any useful code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Please use logic names for your variables, you script become unreadable if you use variable names like `match`, `real_match`, `match1`, `match2`.

```
echo '<pre>';
$data = array(
    array(
        'Kolkata Knight Riders v Delhi Daredevils',
        'Kolkata',
    ),
    // ...
);

foreach ($data as $match) {
    $teams = explode(' v ', $match[0]);
    $teams = array_map(function ($team) {
        return trim(str_replace(' ', '', $team));
    }, $teams);

    // do something with the 2 normalized teams in $teams

    var_dump($teams);
}
```

Comment: $teams is empty string when I populate it through print_r ($teams);

Comment: @nandla well, you understand it now, but after 3 weeks, you don't know where those names come from. Use good variable names for your code readability, not only for us.

Comment: @nandla fixed now, there was some problem.

Comment: @nandla, well then you are doing something wrong. The script works: http://codepad.org/ycUxy3M4 (a minor change because <PHP5.3 don't support callbacks, which is the version that codepad use)